# What is wrong with this proof about the maximizer of a quadratic equation?

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

Working through Daniel Solow's "How to read and do proofs", I have been stuck at the following problem.

Problem:

> What is wrong with the proof below for the statement.
>    If a, b, and c are real numbers with $a< 0$ and $x_∗$ is a maximizer of the function $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$, then for every real number $\epsilon > 0$, $\epsilon \leqslant (2ax_∗ + b)/a$.

Proof: Let $\epsilon > 0$. It will be shown that $\epsilon \leqslant (2ax_* + b)/a$. Because $x_*$ is a maximum of $f$, by definition, for every real number $x$, $f(x_*) \geqslant f(x)$. Thus, for $x = x_∗ − \epsilon$, you have that
$$
\begin{align*}
  ax_*^2 + bx_∗ +c &\geqslant a(x_* −\epsilon)^2 +b(x_∗ −ε)+c \\
    &= ax_∗^2 +bx_∗ +c−(b+2ax_∗)ε+aε^2.
\end{align*}
$$
Subtracting $ax_∗^2 + bx_∗ + c$ from both sides and dividing by $\epsilon > 0$, it follows that 
$$ 
  aε − (b + 2ax_∗) \leqslant 0.
$$
The result that $\epsilon \leqslant (2ax_∗ + b)/a$ follows by adding $b + 2ax_∗$ to both sides of the foregoing inequality and dividing by $a$.

If I substitute the maximizer value, $(-b/2a)$ for $x_*$ the problem statement would lead to $\epsilon\leqslant 0$ which contradicts initial statement that $\epsilon\geqslant 0$. Can anyone spot what the error is?

Thanks in advance S

Comment: what do you know about a?

Answer (score 0):

$a\lt 0\iff a=-|a|$ and $x_*=\frac{-b}{2a}=\frac{-b}{-2|a|}=\frac{b}{2|a|}$

Therefore $aε − (b + 2ax_∗) \leqslant 0\iff -|a|ε\le b - 2|a|x_∗=b-\frac{2|a|b}{2|a|}=b-b=0$.

This obvious inequality,$-|a|\epsilon\le 0$, is where it leads  a correct deduction.